# Is there a way to parse a value though json using ajax call or filter the retrieved json data?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, jstree

I'm using a treeview template, all data is displayed correctly, but I need to send a value from `index.php` to `getdata.php`.

I´ve tried with ajax filter on `index.php` page and also trying to parse a value to `getdata.php` without result.

Let's say I have 100 records, parent_id and children and I need to display only one `parent_id` and its children based on a dynamic value `$myid = '123'`

```
<div id="tree-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    //fill data to tree  with AJAX call
//  $('#tree-container').jstree().get_selected(true)[0].text;
    $('#tree-container').jstree({ 
//  $('#tree-container').jstree.select_node('#node_' + nodes[0])({ 
//  $('#tree-container').jstree('select_node', '120')({
    'plugins': ["wholerow"],
        'core' : {
            'data' : {
                "url" : "getdata.php",
                "dataType" : "json"
            }
        }
    }) 
});
</script>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you buddy

Comment: I wrote it as an answer instead so you can accept it, which will mark the question as "answered".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the id in the URL. Change the URL to:

```
"url" : "getdata.php?myId=123"
```

Then in your `getdata.php`-file, you can get the data using:

```
$myId = $_GET['myId'] ?? null;
```

(If the `$_GET['myId']` doesn't exist, the above will set the variable to `null`)